# How to compare strings without using mysql queries?

Tags: php, string, compare

```
Table1: id, cr_id 
10 | 81
10 | 82

Table2: cr_id, name
80 | Title80
81 | Title81
82 | Title82
83 | Title83
```

I have two mysql queries for them (getting results with `mysql_fetch_array()`). I'm doing a html select box, in which some values will be selected.

How to compare strings `cr_id.Table1` and `cr_id.Table2` without using mysql query?

Upd. I want to achieve a php function which will return "selected" if cr_id.Table1==ccr_id.Table2 and Null if the not.

Upd2. What's wrong?

```
function checked($result_creative, $result_creative_chkd) {
                $select_row = null;
                if( strcmp( $result_creative['creative_id'], $result_creative_chkd['creative_id']) == 0)
                    {
                        $select_row = 'selected';
                    }
                };

            $query_creative_chkd=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM s_s_creative WHERE $id=id");
            $creative_chkd=mysql_num_rows($query_creative_chkd);
                if($creative_chkd != 0) 
                    {
                        while ($result_creative_chkd = mysql_fetch_array($query_creative_chkd)) 
                        {
                        $creative_s_id_chkd = $result_creative_chkd['id'];
                        $creative_id_chkd = $result_creative_chkd['creative_id'];
                        }
                    };

            $query_creative=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM s_creative ORDER BY creative_id ASC");
            $numrows_creative=mysql_num_rows($query_creative);
                if($numrows_creative != 0) 
                    {
                    while ($result_creative = mysql_fetch_array($query_creative)) 
                        {
                        $creative_id = $result_creative['creative_id'];
                        $creative_name = $result_creative['name'];

                        $select_row = checked($result_creative, $result_creative_chkd);

                        echo "<option value=\"".$creative_id."\" ". $select_row ." >".$creative_name."</option>\n  ";   
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: In what way do you need to compare them? What do you want to achieve? (please edit it in you question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the comparison operator:

```
if( $row['cr_id'] == $row2['cr_id'])
```

OR, use the case sensitive string compare function [strcmp](http://php.net/strcmp)

```
if( strcmp( $row['cr_id'], $row2['cr_id']) == 0)
```

OR, use the case insensitive string compare function [strcasecmp](http://php.net/strcasecmp)

```
if( strcasecmp( $row['cr_id'], $row2['cr_id']) == 0)
```

**Edit:**

> Upd. I want to achieve a php function which will return "selected" if 
>   cr_id.Table1==ccr_id.Table2 and Null if the not.

You can use any of the above methods to check if the two strings are equal, and set your variable appropriately. E.g.

```
// Case sensitive string compare:
$selected = null;
if( strcmp( $row['cr_id'], $row2['cr_id']) == 0)
{
    $selected = 'selected';
}
```

**Edit:** You have an error with your function (it's not returning anything). Try this:

```
function checked( $result_creative, $result_creative_chkd) 
{    
    return ( strcmp( $result_creative['creative_id'], $result_creative_chkd['creative_id']) == 0) ? 'selected' : null;
}
```

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd solution can eventually perform a little bit better, (if you have huge amount of comparison to perform :D )

Comment: I already tried that. It's returned false values cause $row and $row2 have diffrent number of values.

Comment: @user1056252 - I added an edit to fix your `checked` function.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about return. But whatever, that didn't solved a problem. It's selecting only the last string of `$result_creative_chkd['creative_id']`. For each `$result_creative['creative_id']` he returns in this function only the last string of `$result_creative_chkd['creative_id']`. Don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function testselected(row1, row2)  {
   if(strcmp( $row['row1'] == $row['row2']))
       echo "Selected.";
   else
       echo "Null.";
```

}

you can also assign the result to a variable if you like as such:

```
function testselected(row1, row2)  {
   $selectstr = ""
   $nullstr = ""
   if(strcmp( $row['row1'] == $row['row2']))
       $selectstr = "Selected."
   else
       $nullstr = "NULL."
```

}

Then you can call the variables wherever you want to display the message.  Hope this helps.

You would call the function as follows:

testselected(id_1, id_2);

Where id_1 and id_2 are the names of the string fields you are comparing.